# How to close the newly popup window in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I click on one button, it goes to another screen and one new popup window appeared. I don't know how to close. Can any one help me out this?  Im using Eclipse for writing code.

Comment: Please add more details. Is this pop-up native browser pop up, or a web element. If it is webElement, add html please.

Comment: I need to close the child window and go to parent window..How can I do it ?Thanks for ur interest.

Comment: You should add more details, it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: After you click on the button, wait for few secs to get the new window to open and count the number of windows present. If you get count more than one, switch to newly opened child window and use close() method to close. To calculate count use : `new WebDriver().getWindowHandles.size()`. This returns number of windows currently opened by Webdriver in an integer format.

Comment: Give control to child window and then close it.

Answer (score 0):

If the child window is a HTML window then you can close the window by using `driver.close()` syntax. Here assume driver is instantiated properly.

If it is a Native or OS window then it is not possible to handle it through selenium.